# Implementing __getattr__ inside a class method such as __call__

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've created a module inspired heavily by [amoffat's sh module](https://github.com/amoffat/sh), where I can import shell programs as functions; unlike `sh`, my module can do something like `git(C = path).commit(m = message)` directly, by returning the module class itself as a partial: `return partial(bakery, self.program)`. However, I've lost the ability to run something like `ls()` without a placeholder method like `ls._()`, which doesn't look as good. The code in the latter: `return output_as_list(args, kwargs)`.

```py
from functools import partial

def __getattr__(name):
    if name == "__path__":
        raise AttributeError
    return bakery(name)

class bakery:
    def __init__(self, program):
        self.program = program
    def __getattr__(self, subcommand):
        return subcommand
    @property
    def __call__(self):
        return partial(bakery, self.program)
```

**My question is this:**

Is there a way to tell `__call__` you're accessing a dynamic attribute, using a `__getattr__` inside it, for example, to implement both the `git(C = path).commit(m = message)` and `ls()` scenarios? Or to conditionally return a partial or an output list depending on whether an attribute of `__call__` is being accessed?

---

### Edit:

I was wondering if something similar to this might work?

```py
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    class inner_class:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.args = args
            self.kwargs = kwargs
        def __getattr__(self, subcommand):
            return partial(bakery, self.program)
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return bakery(*self.args, **self.kwargs)._get_output_as_list(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner_class(self.program, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

### Edit 2:

I suppose I could just convert the individual `__call__` functions to subclasses, and import from whichever is necessary.

Comment: Can you give a smaller example with actual code? It's not clear to me what your problem is.

Comment: My code is kind of all over the place; could you give me a specific example of what to provide?

Comment: You tell us that `git()` works, but `ls()` does not. Show the code for these two functions (? classes ?)

Comment: I'm using [`sarge`](https://sarge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to call them as shell programs after initializing my `bakery` class using `__getattr__` in the `__init__` file; so basically `from bakery import git, ls`. Sorry, I should have specified!

Comment: And what is `bakery`? Please update the question with all this relevant code.

Comment: I added a link to my repository branch! I'm not good with adding details, so if you need anything else, just ask!

Comment: @ShadowRylander i'm not sure you'll find much candidate willing to read your whole repo just to understand your question. Please edit your question with a proper [mcve].

Comment: I don't think there's a way to properly disambiguate `ls()` from `ls().something` in python, just because of the order of execution of stuff. That said, it might be a good idea to have *all* execution functionality in a `.execute()` method of some sort, instead of doing so automatically when you're finished with the whole command chain. So your bakery would serve as a *command builder* and then would `execute()` when done building.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I think that does it? I'm not sure how much I can expand on that.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Would a custom inner class work, under `__call__`?

Comment: @ShadowRylander that's better indeed, voting to reopen .

Comment: `__call__` doesn't have anything to do with the *use* of the thing it returns. The problem is that you expect `ls()` to actually run a command, but `git()` is supposed to return an object that runs a command when it returns. `__call__` can't see into the future to see which is which, because something like `x = git(...); ...; x.commit(...)` is perfectly legal.

Comment: @chepner Can we not use an inner class to return a class for a `git` situation and function for an `ls` situation, similar to my edit?

Comment: `git` and `ls` are inherently different things; you have to model them differently. In some sense, `ls` is closer to a subclass of something like `RunnableCommand`, while `git` would be a subclass of `RunnableCommandBuilder`: it would have methods for creating instance of `RunnableCommand` (like `commit`) which actually map to a shell command.

Comment: @chepner Would this be in reference to the shell versions, or versions built natively in python? Or both?